# frame does not contain a definition of SourcePageType

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, xaml-islands

Im trying to setup a navigation for my wpf app with xaml islands but cant navigate between the views. I get an error:

```
frame does not contain a definition of SourcePageType
```

MainWindow.cs:

```
    private void On_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (NavView.Child is NavigationView navigationView) {
            // NavView.IsBackEnabled = ContentFrame.CanGoBack;
            navView = navigationView;
            if (ContentFrame.Content?.GetType() == typeof(SettingsPage))
            {
                // SettingsItem is not part of NavView.MenuItems, and doesn't have a Tag.
                navView.SelectedItem = (NavigationViewItem)navView.SettingsItem;
                navView.Header = "Settings";
            }
            else if (ContentFrame.Content != null)
            {
                var item = _pages.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Page == e.Content);

                navView.SelectedItem = navView.MenuItems
                    .OfType<NavigationViewItem>()
                    .First(n => n.Tag.Equals(item.Tag));

                navView.Header =
                    ((NavigationViewItem)navView.Content)?.Content?.ToString();
            }
    } 
}
```

I think there is something wrong with the NavView_Loaded method to catch the selected item? Arnt there any examples for navigations in xaml islands?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `System.Windows.Controls.Frame` class in WPF has no `SourcePageType` property and this has nothing to do with Xaml Islands.

If you want to know the type of the `Page` that is currently loaded into the `Frame`, you could call the `GetType()` method on its `Content` property:

```
private void On_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{

    if (ContentFrame.Content?.GetType() == typeof(SettingsPage))
    {
        navView.SelectedItem = (NavigationViewItem)navView.SettingsItem;
        navView.Header = "Settings";
    }
    else if (ContentFrame.Content != null)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, but now I got errors for: WindowsXamlHost does not contain a definition for Settingsitem, SelectedItem and MenuItems, Header. Ive updated the on_Navigate function.

Comment: @CodCase: Of couse the WindowsXamlHost itself hasn't got any of these properties. Its `Child` may have though depending on the value of `InitialTypeName`.

Comment: ok now I think I have that. The Navigation is showing and is collabpseable but I still cant navigate to the pages. Ive updated my code to current version.

Comment: @CodCase: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. Your original question was about the `SourcePageType` property not being found.